# Having same NavigationDrawer in all acitivies

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have followed a bunch of examples for implementing the same NavigationDrawer in all activities so far no success.
I have 2 issues:

1.
I Have defined a BaseActivity and Override its setContentView.
BUT in setContentView I don't seem to be able to access the ListView containing my NavDrawer items.
(drawerListView returns null)

2. How am I supposed to reuse the code for my NavDrawer? I could not find a good example here. 
   I don't like to add a DrawerLayout, FrameLayout and ListView to all my Fragment layout xmls.
   Right now the only solution to have NavigationDrawer in all my pages that comes to my mind is like this:

I change my fragment layouts so that the whole xml is embedded in a frame layout like this:
so that all my fragments layouts have THEIR own NavDrawer. This is what I DO'NT like and I know is 
a bad solution. (I'm not even sure if this will work and in my BaseActivity I won't face difficulties having many ListViews with the same id ("drawerList") and many FrameLayouts with the same id....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    all my xml content to form a fragment

</FrameLayout>

<!-- Use any Views you like -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawerList"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

What am I supposed to do? any good and clear example is highly appreciated.

The code for my BaseActivity

```
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener
{
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private String[] properties;
private ListView drawerListView;


protected DrawerLayout fullLayout;
protected FrameLayout actContent;

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    Intent intent2=new Intent(BaseActivity.this, ActivitySearchForSale.class);
    startActivity(intent2);

}
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    fullLayout= (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, null); // Your base layout here
    actContent= (FrameLayout) fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
    properties = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.propertyTypeArray);
    drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, properties));
    drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener((OnItemClickListener) this);

    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, actContent, true); // Setting the content of layout your provided to the act_content frame

    super.setContentView(fullLayout);
}
```

The code for my activity_main.xml i which I have defined the DrawerLayout and I don't know how to include this in my other fragment layouts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/mainContent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TextView 
    style="@style/StyleForSimpleTextView"
    android:text="zzzzz"
    />
</FrameLayout>

<!-- Use any Views you like -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawerList"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My activity_search_for_sale.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.*.*.ActivitySearchForSale"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

My fragment_search_for_sale

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    >

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llSearchForSale"
style="@style/StyleForParentVerticalLinearLayouts">
.

.


.

   </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

Java class for activity:

```
public class ActivitySearchForSale extends BaseActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_for_sale);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, FragmentSearchForSale.newInstance(3)).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

And I have a java class for my fragment which onCreateView is as follows:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView;
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_for_sale, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to find the `drawerList` view in the layout you just inflated.

Instead you tried to `findViewById` on the activity's content which was not yet set.

Furthermore it looks like your trying to cast the DrawerLayout to a FrameLayout which is probably not what you wanted.

Create a layout that holds your Drawer (e.g. `drawer_layout.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawerList"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="left"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Override the `setContentView` in your `BaseActivity` like this:

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    // All activities share the drawer
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.drawer_layout, null);
    drawerListView = (ListView) fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
    properties = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.propertyTypeArray);
    drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, properties));
    drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener((OnItemClickListener) this);

    // After creating the drawer add the activity's layout as the first child
    ViewGroup layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, null);
    drawer.addView(layout, 0);

    super.setContentView(fullLayout);
}
```

Now your `activity_main.xml` will look like:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView 
        style="@style/StyleForSimpleTextView"
        android:text="zzzzz"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

And you set it with:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

This will work for all of your activities as long as they `extend BaseActivity`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  actContent= (FrameLayout) fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.mainContent);           and        drawerListView = (ListView) fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList); (from your answer) worked to get the list view. But what about the layout files? How am I supposed to change them?

Comment: @Tina I've updated my answer to reflect on your first comment. Your 2nd comment is unclear, please explain it further.

Comment: @Tina I've noticed another error in your code. Combined my answers to code that should work. Give it a go.

Comment: I edited my question. Hope I could express myself a bit better about second issue. Your code just works for my activity_main (not my other activities like activity_search_for_sale). the drawerListView is null (which is expected because I dont have a ListView with the id "drawerList" in fragment_search_for_sale nor do I know how to add one in it!! (without copy pasting the code from activity_main of course)...

Comment: @Tina okay I finally understood what you meant. Updated with (hopefully) a clear answer.

Comment: I have 4 words for u : U R A GENIOUS. Thanks. (oops 5!)

Comment: @Tina nah, I'm not ^^ but thank you and you're welcome.